# Good open-source bug tracking / issue tracking sofware for Windows

Tags: windows, open-source, bug-tracking, issue-tracking

Besides the painful-to-install non-Windows [Bugzilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/), what open-source issue tracking programs can be recommended that are just as good but available as a regular windows-style install? (`.exe` or `.msi`)

Comment: Bugzilla is written in Perl... Perl can be installed on windows.  Are you asking for a bug tracker that is a single windows executable?

Comment: tried to install bugzilla via the instructions using CVS install here but the login to mozilla (anonymous) doesn't even work! https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Win32Install#Installing_Bugzilla_on_Microsoft_Windows

Comment: Problem is I don't know if this crap works on 64-bit Server 2008, can't even get crappy CVSNT working on it.

Answer (score 7):

You can try [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) - a painless installation is provided by [BitNami Redmine stack](http://bitnami.org/stack/redmine).

Comment: looks like it only runs over mySQL or is it local file system based?

Comment: It can be configured to use either MySQL, PostgreSQL or SQLite. However, I believe that BitNami comes preconfigured with MySQL. Btw, the stack will install everything you need: Apache, MySQL, Ruby, Redmine and perhaps something else as well.

Answer (score 7):

I have been working with [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) for the last three weeks and it's love!
You can use [Bitnami Stack](http://bitnami.org/stack/redmine) to setup and running in few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Never used it, but [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) might be of use here. And yes, it does have a [damn .exe](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDownload). :)

Comment: :) 
weird, just went there but do not see a download for an .exe in the list

Comment: @coffeeaddict: that's odd because i do see http://ftp.edgewall.com/pub/trac/Trac-0.11.4.win32.exe

Comment: Trac is easily extendable by plugins and there are tons of them on the web. Every 3 months someone comes to my office and says "I found this replacement of Trac, a XXX, and it has the BBB functionality, lets switch it!", and I say "but it doesn't have X, Y and Z functionality. How about We could add BBB to Trac with a plugin". And it's like "oh, I haven't thought about that, XXX doesn't have a plugin system". "Right.". I wish You have fun using it.